# Confused About Play2 Form Submission (login/register)

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

This might seem very basic, but I am new to JPA/Ebean and Play Framework (not so new with Java btw).

I'm trying to make two forms. One to log in and one to register. I'm using both the book Play for Java MEAP (Early Access), the official website documentation, and the sample app "ZenTask" codes. I must say Play is strong, robust, but the documentation is so poor. I get this must have something to do with most Play users are seasoned Java Web developers, but still!

I created a model called User

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account")
public class User extends Model {

    @Id
    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    public String email;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String displayName;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String password;

    public static Model.Finder<String, User> find = new Model.Finder(String.class, User.class);

    public static User authenticate(String email, String password) {
    return find.where()
            .eq("email", email)
            .eq("password", password)
            .findUnique();
    }
}
```

Then I have this controller Application

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public static class Login {
        @Constraints.Required
        public String email;
        public String password;

        public String validate() {
           if (User.authenticate(email,password)==null) {
              return "Invalid email or password.";
           }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static class Register {

        @Constraints.Required
        public String email;
        public String password;
        public String cfmPassword;
        public String displayName;

        public String validate() {
            if (cfmPassword.equals(password)) {
                return "Passwords typed in does not match.";
            } else if (displayName.contains(" ")) {
                return "Display name cannot contain space";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't even understand why am I creating two nested classes, but it seems like a requirement to create forms in Play? So I made two. This is the code I use to render the page (it's inside Controller Application)

```
public static Result index() {
    return ok(index.render(form(Login.class), form(Register.class)));
}
```

OK, now here comes the most frustrated part. First, I don't know if I have truly authenticated the user when logged in: (codes in Application)

```
/**
 * Handle login form submission.
 */
public static Result authenticate() {
    Form<Login> loginForm = form(Login.class).bindFromRequest();
    if (loginForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(index.render(loginForm, form(Register.class)));
    } else {
        session("email", loginForm.get().email);
        return redirect(controllers.routes.Wall.index());
    }
}
```

Second, how can I say a user's information when he/she registers. I copied these lines from the Java for Play book, but it doesn't work (my IDE says it's wrong..type mismatch)

```
 public static Result register() {
    Form<Register> RegisterForm = form(Register.class).bindFromRequest();

    if (RegisterForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(index.render(form(Login.class), RegisterForm));
    } else {
        User user = RegisterForm.get();
        session("email", RegisterForm.get().email);
        return redirect(controllers.routes.Wall.initiate());
    }
}
```

I must have done something really really wrong here..can anyone enlighten me a bit?

Comment: 1. What do you mean you don't know? loginForm.hasErrors() calls validate() of your Login class, which checks if the user with such email and password exists.

Comment: 2. You should have save() method in your controller. It should bind registerForm from request. Get the user. And save the user.

Comment: Ha! I guessed the first question right! In fact I can't even find anything in the Play documentation about this matter. For the second, I tried to bind registerForm...and it was not very successful (type mismatch)

Comment: From your explanation I have no idea at which line was the type mismatch. You are returning  badRequest(index.render(form(Login.class), RegisterForm)). Which probably should be badRequest(index.render(RegisterForm,form(Register.class)).

Comment: My apology, cosmolev. User user = RegisterForm.get() is a mismatch, because RegisterForm.get() returns a Register class but user is a User (model) class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK...sorry. I have solved my problem. Here is how I handled the type mismatch problem. It turns out that I should have used User class from the model directly instead of creating new nested classes such as "Login" and "Register."

I add these lines into my register() method under my Application controller.

```
User user = new User();
user.email = RegisterForm.get().email;
user.displayName = RegisterForm.get().displayName;
user.password = RegisterForm.get().password;
user.save();
```

**My question now is: "is validate() method a reserved method in Play framework that will be called by default from Form.hasErrors()? If I use my User class to construct my form and invoke .hasErrors(), since I don't have validate() method in User class, what will Play framework invoke to check error then? Is it better off for me to use a nested class or should I use classes from models directly?"**

Comment: IMHO, I can see no strong reasoning to use inner classes in a general case.  I'd build the forms directly from the models.

Comment: That's what I feel!! Thanks, but what will happen if you invoke Form.hasErrors() when a Model class is used? Which method (created within the model class) is Play invoking to validate your data?

Comment: TL;DR: Form.hasErrors() will continue working. None, it's automagic.  
Long answer: I tried to confirm this by looking at the source but haven't found out for sure yet, so I'm just making a WASG, but I think the only validation done is based on the constraints you've put on the fields in the model. (@Required fields aren't null, @Format fields have compliant formatting, etc) I'll try to find a source reference, but I can say that this is how my app seems to work.

Comment: I agree when you use model class, Form.hasErrors() checks constraints. Well when I have a subclass inside my controller with "validation()" method, it actually went ahead and called this method..so I'm wondering if it is by reserved words like validate or something else. Thanks anyway :)