# Play display error from Constraints

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have just discovered there is a package called `play.data.validation.Constraints` and it can help check if an email address is valid. So I used it when constructing a subclass for a form.

```
public static class Subclass1 {
    @Constraints.email
    public String email;

    public String validate() {
      ......
    }
}
```

Normally inside the validate() method, I return strings back to views to indicate certain errors. Well, I can't figure out a way to tell a user if the email address is valid or invalid, because of this `@Constraints.email`. Can anyone tell me how to return an error under this circumstance?

Also I have a whole bunch of `@Constraints.required`, it would be nice knowing how to display these errors as well. Btw, I don't really use form helper...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried 'Handling binding failure' in [JavaForms](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaForms)? Another example here [confused-about-play2-form-submission-login-register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679170/confused-about-play2-form-submission-login-register)